# Increase Partition Size Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I want to partition /dev/sda5 and merge the unallocated space with /dev/sda6. How to do it? I've searched for many ways to do it but I couldn't understand much to proceed. Please help!!

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAqEH.jpg) is the snapshot of my GParted window.

Comment: What do you mean by "partition /dev/sda5". Do you want to create a new partition in /dev/sda5 or want to completely merge it in /dev/sda6 ?

Comment: I want to create a new partition in /dev/sda5 and merge it with the /dev/sda6

Answer (score 1):

Boot from gparted live cd http://gparted.org/livecd.php

- If you dont't want to have /dev/sda5 partition any more right click on it and remove - **this 100MB of data will be lost**. (You can't do this right now because it is mounted). Right click on /dev/sda6 and resize.
- or down size /dev/sda5 and then resize dev/sda6

**Be aware that there is always risk, so make backups**

Answer (score 0):

You must boot from a live-dvd/usb.

Once in the live-session run gparted with root attributes:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
gparted
```

From gparted, unmount partitions, delete /dev/sda5, increase /dev/sda6 merging the unallocated space with /dev/sda6.

Possibly Ubuntu becomes unusable.

Continue running:

```
blkid /dev/sda6 #The output will say like: xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/fstab
#Change in these lines the correct UUID
 ---------------------
#/dev/sda6 was / 
UUID=xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx / ext4    defaults        0       0
 ---------------------
#Control+O, save file. Contro+X, Close nano.
update-grub
umount /mnt
reboot
```